# Cannot link an application with libavcodec

Tags: linux, gcc, video, ffmpeg, libavcodec

I'm trying to make a simplest app with usage of ffmpeg libs.
Here is my code:

main.c:

```
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>

int main()
{

    avformat_network_init();
    return 0;
}
```

compiler command:

```
gcc -o main main.c -Wall  -lavformat -lavcodec -lswresample -lswscale -lavutil -lm -lz -lpthread -L/usr/local/lib/
```

leads to :

> /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(matroskaenc.o): In function
>   `get_aac_sample_rates':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/matroskaenc.c:709: undefined
>   reference to`avpriv_mpeg4audio_get_config2'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/matroskaenc.c:709: undefined
>   reference to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_get_config2'
>   /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(mux.o): In function`
>   ff_interleave_add_packet':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/mux.c:936: undefined
>   reference to `av_packet_make_refcounted'
>   /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(utils.o): In function`
>   ff_packet_list_put':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/utils.c:461: undefined
>   reference to `av_packet_make_refcounted'
>   /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(utils.o): In function`parse_packet':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/utils.c:1494: undefined
>   reference to `av_packet_make_refcounted'
>   /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(utils.o): In function`ff_read_packet':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/utils.c:876: undefined
>   reference to `av_packet_make_refcounted'
>   /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(codec2.o): In function`
>   codec2_read_header_common':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/codec2.c:74: undefined
>   reference to `avpriv_codec2_mode_bit_rate'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/codec2.c:75: undefined
>   reference to`avpriv_codec2_mode_frame_size'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/codec2.c:76: undefined
>   reference to `avpriv_codec2_mode_block_align'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/codec2.c:74: undefined
>   reference to`avpriv_codec2_mode_bit_rate'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/codec2.c:75: undefined
>   reference to `avpriv_codec2_mode_frame_size'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/codec2.c:76: undefined
>   reference to`avpriv_codec2_mode_block_align'
>   /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(isom.o): In function
>   `ff_mp4_read_dec_config_descr':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/isom.c:552: undefined
>   reference to`avpriv_mpeg4audio_get_config2'
>   /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(latmenc.o): In function
>   `latm_decode_extradata':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/latmenc.c:65: undefined
>   reference to`avpriv_mpeg4audio_get_config2'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/latmenc.c:65: undefined
>   reference to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_get_config2'
>   /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(matroskadec.o): In function`
>   matroska_decode_buffer':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1657:
>   undefined reference to `BZ2_bzDecompressInit'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1672:
>   undefined reference to`BZ2_bzDecompress'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1665:
>   undefined reference to `BZ2_bzDecompressEnd'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/matroskadec.c:1675:
>   undefined reference to`BZ2_bzDecompressEnd'
>   /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(mxfenc.o): In function
>   `get_ue_golomb_31':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/./libavcodec/golomb.h:140: undefined
>   reference to`ff_ue_golomb_vlc_code'
>   /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(mxfenc.o): In function
>   `mxf_parse_dnxhd_frame':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/mxfenc.c:2030: undefined
>   reference to`avpriv_dnxhd_get_hr_frame_size'
>   /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(rtpenc_vc2hq.o): In function
>   `init_get_bits_xe':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/./libavcodec/get_bits.h:628: undefined
>   reference to`ff_interleaved_golomb_vlc_len'
>   /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(rtpenc_vc2hq.o): In function
>   `get_interleaved_ue_golomb':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/./libavcodec/golomb.h:197: undefined
>   reference to`ff_interleaved_dirac_golomb_vlc_code'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/./libavcodec/golomb.h:185: undefined
>   reference to `ff_interleaved_dirac_golomb_vlc_code'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/./libavcodec/golomb.h:197: undefined
>   reference to`ff_interleaved_dirac_golomb_vlc_code'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/./libavcodec/golomb.h:197: undefined
>   reference to `ff_interleaved_dirac_golomb_vlc_code'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/./libavcodec/golomb.h:185: undefined
>   reference to`ff_interleaved_dirac_golomb_vlc_code'
>   /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(rtpenc_vc2hq.o):/home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/./libavcodec/golomb.h:185:
>   more undefined references to `ff_interleaved_dirac_golomb_vlc_code'
>   follow /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(rtpenc_vc2hq.o): In function`
>   get_interleaved_ue_golomb':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/./libavcodec/golomb.h:183: undefined
>   reference to `ff_interleaved_ue_golomb_vlc_code'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/./libavcodec/golomb.h:183: undefined
>   reference to`ff_interleaved_ue_golomb_vlc_code'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/./libavcodec/golomb.h:183: undefined
>   reference to `ff_interleaved_ue_golomb_vlc_code'
>   /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(spdifdec.o): In function`
>   spdif_get_offset_and_codec':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/spdifdec.c:63: undefined
>   reference to `av_adts_header_parse'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/spdifdec.c:63: undefined
>   reference to`av_adts_header_parse'
>   /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(spdifenc.o): In function
>   `spdif_header_aac':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/spdifenc.c:362: undefined
>   reference to`av_adts_header_parse'
>   /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(ac3dec.o): In function `ac3_eac3_probe':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/ac3dec.c:63: undefined
>   reference to`av_ac3_parse_header'
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/ac3dec.c:60: undefined
>   reference to `av_ac3_parse_header'
>   /usr/local/lib//libavformat.a(adtsenc.o): In function`
>   adts_decode_extradata':
>   /home/ievdokimov/repos/FFmpeg/libavformat/adtsenc.c:56: undefined
>   reference to `avpriv_mpeg4audio_get_config2' collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the `libavformat.so`file version is different from other libraries.
Please check the version compatible with other libraries like `liavcodec`

Comment: That makes sence. I've tried it on the other system and that worked  well. Thanks!